# CLR Profiler 2.0 does not work on .NET 4.0 Client Profile WPF application

Tags: .net-4.0, clrprofiler

I have a WPF application that is targeting the .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile.

When I run it from the CLR Profiler 2.0 (which runs with administrative rights), the application starts and runs normally, but the CLR Profiler does not show any information on it. When I hit 'Show Heap Now', it freezes for some time, and then displays the message 'There was no response from the application'. When the application terminates, it displays the 'profiler results', which are all '0' or 'Unknown'.

I'm working on Windows 7 x86 Professional

Is there a CLR profiler for .NET 4.0?

Any hints are appreciated

Thanks, Jonas

Comment: Currently, I don't believe there is a a version of `CLR Profiler` for .NET 4.0.

Comment: [There is now.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be2d842b-fdce-4600-8d32-a3cf74fda5e1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one worked for me

http://communistgames.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-nprof-011-and-clrprofiler-in-net.html

EDIT: Unfortunately, that link is dead, but now there is a CLR profiler for .NET 4:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273

Comment: Hi @cheeesus, your link redirected to another page, can't found the article